# Jersey: location header URI not created correctly

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

My POST method returns a CREATED response using the following code:

```
    URI location = null;
    try {
        location = new URI("example");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.created(location).build();
```

The location header that i get in response on my browser/postman is :

```
base-path-to-my-webapp/example
```

while i am expecting `base-path-to-my-web-app/current-path/example`

I tried to look for the issue online. I got https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2838 which says that the issue is resolved, and if we POST to `current-path/`(with a trailing slash) we should get the correct response.

This does not seem to work for me. I am using Jersey 2.23.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Migrating from Jersey 2.22 to 2.22.1](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-2.22.1). It describes the changes made. If you want the behavior you are expecting, setting the property

> [`ServerProperties.LOCATION_HEADER_RELATIVE_URI_RESOLUTION_RFC7231`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.34/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#LOCATION_HEADER_RELATIVE_URI_RESOLUTION_RFC7231)

to `true` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried setting this to true in web.xml like this :
<init-param>
     <param-name>ServerProperties.LOCATION_HEADER_RELATIVE_URI_RESOLUTION_RFC7231</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
, doesn't work

Comment: Click javadoc the link. Use the string value in mentioned in the Javadoc. You can't use constants like that in the web.xml. You need to use the actual string value of that constant

Comment: yeah, mea culpa. got the string value "jersey.config.server.headers.location.relative.resolution.rfc7231" . It works now

Comment: I tried this setting the system property from Java, and it still does not work. I have no access to the web.xml, is there any other way to produce relative paths?

Comment: @Tu.ma You don't need web.xml. You can set this property in an Application class or a ResourceConfig class

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet, I tried
System.getProperties().setProperty(ServerProperties.LOCATION_HEADER_RELATIVE_URI_RESOLUTION_RFC7231, "true"); with no luck (of course called at startup)

Comment: @Tu.ma What I meant was that you can use `property()` if you are using `ResourceConfig` or override `Map<String, String> getProperties()` if you are using an `Application` class